# Azure minute/hourly metric collection issue using SDK

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-queues

hi i'm trying to get the hourly/minute metrics using the sdk provided by azure but i'm confused ,i got the below result isn't Partition key the Time?
PartitionKey=20170605T1531 RowKey=system;All TimeStamp=Mon Jun 05 21:02:24 IST 2017 
PartitionKey=20170605T1533 RowKey=system;All TimeStamp=Mon Jun 05 21:04:23 IST 2017
PartitionKey=20170605T1539 RowKey=system;All TimeStamp=Mon Jun 05 21:10:24 IST 2017 
PartitionKey=20170605T1540 RowKey=system;All TimeStamp=Mon Jun 05 21:11:24 IST 2017 
Please explain the concept /difference in PartitionKey and TimeStamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please explain the concept /difference in PartitionKey and TimeStamp?

In [Azure Table service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables), each entity has 3 system properties that specify a partition key, a row key, and a **timestamp** column that the Table service uses to track when the entity was last updated (this happens automatically and you cannot manually overwrite the timestamp with an arbitrary value).

Comment: Han Thank you, please help me understand one more thing if time now is 11:15 AM then my partition key should be 20170606T1000-20170606T1100 to get my last hour metrics right? but if i do this there is no output

Comment: Please try to convert the time to UTC, and check the metrics in that partition.

Comment: Han Thank You very much

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, which will help others quick find and fix similar problem.